# How to setup web push notifications on iOS Safari 12th browser version?

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Here is the problem.

I've setup web push notifications on iOS and MacOS using Firebase SDK but it turned out that it doesn't work on older iOS devices with Safari of, the 12th version.

How to setup web push notifications on iOS Safari of 12th browser version? What are the options?

I've read about APNS but still can't figure out how to make it work.

Anybody, please help.

Firebase SDK is not supported.

Comment: Web push notifications are not supported prior to iOS 16.4. If you want push notifications on earlier versions then you must develop an App Store app